# Android Pause execution until StartActivityForResult returns

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK);

            editText.setText(selectContactNumber);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selectContactNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

And I want the editview to change after a contact is selected. But it is not waiting for the contact. It just keeps executing and the result will be null. Is there a way to pause the execution to perform the operations?

Comment: Move the `editText.setText()` call to the `onActivityResult()` method in the calling Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `EditText` in `onActivityResult` method not in the `onClick` one.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PICK) {

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            editText.setText(selectContactNumber);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selectContactNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```